# Does kotlin-native have destructors?

Tags: kotlin, native, kotlin-native

In kotlin native there is memScoped function that automatically free allocated memory when control is going out of scope.
Is there something like destructors for local objects?

Answer (score 18):

Current Kotlin/Native does not provide mechanism for calling a method when certain object is no longer needed in memory (finalizer in Java speech) but inline lambdas easily allow to implement mechanisms, similar to RAII in C++. For example, if you want to be sure, that some resource is always released after leaving certain scope, you may do:

```
class Resource {
  fun take() = println("took")
  fun free() = println("freed")
}

inline fun withResource(resource: Resource, body: () -> Unit) =
 try {
   resource.take()
   body()
 } finally {
   resource.free()
 }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   withResource(Resource()) { 
       println("body") 
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a plan to add destructors at all? Or would you rather not because this kind of deterministic behavior is not possible to achieve anyway with Kotlin's other targets?

Comment: There are no current plan to add general purpose destructors. However, somewhat similar functionality could be achieved with weak references, present in Kotlin/Native.

Comment: I was trying to have a similar functionality using WeakReference, as you mentioned, but still it doesn't seem to work, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-61830/WeakReference-doesnt-work-under-Kotlin-Native  @NikolayIgotti