# destructor in Kotlin programming language

Tags: kotlin, destructor

I am new to Kotlin, have written a class in kotlin to perform database operation

I have defined database connection in constructor using init but I want to close database connection using destructor.

Any Idea of how to achieve this using kotlin destructor?

Currently I have wrote a separate function to close connection, which i want to have it using destructor like any other programming language like php,etc

Comment: I think Kotlin does not have a destructor because Java does not have a destructor. However, Java has a `finalize` method, and more info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171952/is-there-a-destructor-for-java

Comment: That depends the target of kotlin use, for JVM there are no destructors as pointed by @Naetmul see this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747862/does-kotlin-native-have-destructors

Comment: "like any other programming language"---actually not that many languages have them, and absolutely _no_ languages based on tracing garbage collection have them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Handling resources that need to be closed in Kotlin

You can make your Database Wrapper extend [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).  You can then use it like this.

```
val result = MyResource().use { resource ->
    resource.doThing();
}
```

This way inside the use block your resource will be available, afterwards you will get back result, which is what `doThing()` returns, and your resource will be closed. As you haven't stored it in a variable you also avoid accidentally using the resource after it is closed.

## Why to avoid `finalize`

Finalise is not safe, [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=7) describes some of problems with them, such as:

- They are not guaranteed to run at all
- When they do run there can be delays before it runs

The link sums up the problems like this:

> Finalizers are unpredictable, often dangerous, and generally unnecessary. Their use can cause erratic behavior, poor performance, and portability problems. Finalizers have a few valid uses, which we’ll cover later in this item, but as a rule of thumb, you should avoid finalizers.
>
> C++ programmers are cautioned not to think of finalizers as Java’s analog of C++ destructors. In C++, destructors are the normal way to reclaim the resources associated with an object, a necessary counterpart to constructors. In Java, the garbage collector reclaims the storage associated with an object when it becomes unreachable, requiring no special effort on the part of the programmer. C++ destructors are also used to reclaim other nonmemory resources. In Java, the try-finally block is generally used for this purpose.

## If you *really* need to use finalize

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43784223/3585796) shows how to override finalize, but it is a bad idea unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Is there anything prevent the developer from "misuse" in your first example? I am thinking something along the lines of ```val foobar = MyResource(); foobar.doThing();```

Comment: "They are not guaranteed to run at all" That's only because the program can exit. This same issue exists with `Closeable`. Nothing disables the OS's process management or the computer's power button.

Comment: What happens if a kotlin class creates a resource which is used throughout the life of the class, but must be explicitly released before the class is garbage-collected. This is the case, for example, with a ```Broadcaster```.