# Android MVVM Unsubscribing to Observables in Repository Layer

Tags: android, mvvm, observable, repository

I'm using MVVM in an Android project. The usual flow for my operations and data looks like this (just like it should in MVVM).

```
View -> ViewModel -> Repository -> Data Source        [Operation Flow] 
View <- ViewModel <- Repository <- Data Source        [Data Flow]
```

The Data Source has custom `Observable` fields that hold state for a particular data entity. I'm interested in my Repository subscribing to the `Obervables` in Data Source. But since [`Repository` should not have any Android lifecycle attached to it](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-livedata-in-your-repository-there-are-better-options-25a7557b0730) and [Kotlin has no destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747862/does-kotlin-native-have-destructors), how can I unsubscribe to the `Observable` just before my `Repository` is destroyed to avoid memory leaks?